# Слайдер Bootstrap 4 с несколькими элементами

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Как можно сделать в слайдере несколько активных элементов?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
        <div id="carousel-example-1z" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
          <!--Indicators-->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <!--/.Indicators-->
          <!--Slides-->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!--First slide-->
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <!--/First slide-->
            <!--Second slide-->
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(129).jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <!--/Second slide-->
            <!--Third slide-->
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
            <!--/Third slide-->
          </div>
          <!--/.Slides-->
          <!--Controls-->
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
          <!--/.Controls-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Comment: суть вопроса не ясна (

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE нужно чтобы на первом слайде вместо одно фотографии было несколько блоков

Comment: Переопределять стили необходимо для слайдера, ищите в документации или же используйте другие слайдеры, к примеру - swiper slider